featureUtility installServerFeatures gets "CWWKF1390E: The configured Maven Repository cannot be reached. " on container
I'm trying to build a container for open liberty on podman following the steps here - https://openliberty.io/guides/containerize-podman.html.
It looks like the RUN features.sh step is failing because it can't reach the internet, but this is strange error.  I ran both a yum install nano and curl www.google.com on this container and they both succeeded.  Why are those commands able to hit the internet but not features.sh?
The error I get is below.  Also, why is the error referencing maven and not open liberty?  FYI, im running this at work so there is a network proxy involved  but from my desktop the proxy is transparent.
C:\dev\rn-container\guide-containerize-podman>podman build -t system:1.0-SNAPSHOT finish/system/.
STEP 1/8: FROM icr.io/appcafe/open-liberty:kernel-slim-java11-openj9-ubi
Trying to pull icr.io/appcafe/open-liberty:kernel-slim-java11-openj9-ubi...
Getting image source signatures
Checking if image destination supports signatures
Copying blob sha256:9d876d7610f48b3b4c1fc2a7b9583ad2ec74b526b5a44beff535c389f61c5ee9
Copying blob sha256:930296e19327c9007bd33f3219bb4338cf8a3b20d3fc43c30f6b942cbdce6c51
Copying blob sha256:6d6997a1fd99ba362048be5d498f205f8961a46f7b22cccd6972848997207eff
Copying blob sha256:3df7dc3f800e252b9da6f53995188b66dedc36281d6bc79dfcd5c3b4259d80fc
Copying blob sha256:013e303ca13cc91712c179536acbef2617daafff1af96037ba3f76d363460cee
Copying blob sha256:0ed61360824d890ae6f7caa74dc073f686216d42734f5de00745b68163d12100
Copying blob sha256:8a9b1619fca84c174ec7fb46203df1149e93147e3a41d7ebcd2ead8fa4278a41
Copying blob sha256:c4f8bfb1b69f860bd698322a38d752d10d7d2ecb0334fcb343935919cda94264
Copying blob sha256:03a33c0a3305670f5f0538f25570d7f6a253b327a9594a1147aec3bdf718ab1a
Copying blob sha256:66e113d9641154158289e09d043c283cd915d1ac07d53b3c76defa208364bb4c
Copying blob sha256:46d83397f193bdbd259c17e6bf7724ce292ce19a7210f570b46ef8a7e3ddc308
Copying blob sha256:6018ccce72d419e19a2568fa66249d97a2d6be5fa3d212f9c997486f1088168c
Copying blob sha256:d3f6e09f7ceee9385c62fdbcbdfe5039b38e44814dd96eee4bb890ed59effa79
Copying blob sha256:27ba61511e7524f5bf78dc7747f3061b4271622b6be12bd0f352100ff76b637d
Copying blob sha256:0f79f8ed1c29c05a15adefcdf4b8747fa99fb615dc07b0e2689e872ec96a1a40
Copying blob sha256:46d0b4827a40eff712cab075bc04755781e783c322e6314d07c17600ce3c2cd8
Copying blob sha256:3777e08b6ba97f913814cd7528ae11e7f12e97dcc143d47c2c53f733f1a085f5
Copying config sha256:7f71d47dd47ee9a219206aa774a4398180139b2ebce10658e310bacbb42df06b
Writing manifest to image destination
Storing signatures
STEP 2/8: ARG VERSION=1.0
--> a6f2921a0454
STEP 3/8: ARG REVISION=SNAPSHOT
--> 59a154f1ae5f
STEP 4/8: LABEL   org.opencontainers.image.authors="Your Name"   org.opencontainers.image.vendor="Open Liberty"   org.opencontainers.image.url="local"   org.opencontainers.image.source="https://github.com/OpenLiberty/guide-containerize-podman"   org.opencontainers.image.version="$VERSION"   org.opencontainers.image.revision="$REVISION"   vendor="Open Liberty"   name="system"   version="$VERSION-$REVISION"   summary="The system microservice from the Containerizing microservices with Podman guide"   description="This image contains the system microservice running with the Open Liberty runtime."
--> 6d5a73d3d417
STEP 5/8: COPY --chown=1001:0 src/main/liberty/config /config/
--> 1caaf3f0abeb
STEP 6/8: RUN features.sh
+ SNIPPETS_SOURCE=/opt/ol/helpers/build/configuration_snippets
+ SNIPPETS_TARGET=/config/configDropins/overrides
+ SNIPPETS_TARGET_DEFAULTS=/config/configDropins/defaults
+ mkdir -p /config/configDropins/overrides
+ mkdir -p /config/configDropins/defaults
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ '[' '' == client ']'
+ '[' '' == embedded ']'
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ '[' '' == true ']'
+ '[' '' == true ']'
+ featureUtility installServerFeatures --acceptLicense defaultServer --noCache
CWWKF1390E: The configured Maven Repository cannot be reached. Verify that your computer has network access and firewalls are configured correctly, then try the action again. If the connection still fails, the repository server might be temporarily unavailable.


The featureUtility downloads features from a maven repository defaulting to maven central if no configuration is provided. The reason the message refers to Maven rather than Open Liberty is because it is attempting to connect to a maven repository. I do not know the context of where you are running the Podman build, but it is possible you are running it in an environment where maven central is blocked by a firewall rule. It is very possible that maven central is blocked, but the yum repositories and google are not. A quick way to test would be to run curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ in the container
